# How to make a dynamic limit in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

I have a table like this:

```
// notifications
+----+--------------+------+---------+------------+
| id |      event   | seen | id_user | time_stamp |
+----+--------------+------+---------+------------+
| 1  | vote         | 1    | 123     | 1464174617 |
| 2  | comment      | 1    | 456     | 1464174664 |
| 3  | vote         | 1    | 123     | 1464174725 |
| 4  | answer       | 1    | 123     | 1464174813 |
| 5  | comment      | NULL | 456     | 1464174928 |
| 6  | comment      | 1    | 123     | 1464175114 |
| 7  | vote         | NULL | 456     | 1464175317 |
| 8  | answer       | NULL | 123     | 1464175279 |
| 9  | vote         | NULL | 123     | 1464176618 |
+----+--------------+------+---------+------------+
```

I'm trying to select at least 15 rows for specific user. Just there is two conditions:

1. Always all unread rows (`seen = NULL`) should be matched, even if they are more than 15 rows.
2. If the number of unread rows is more than 15, then it also should select 2 read rows (`seen = 1`).

---

**Examples:** `read` is the number of read rows and `unread` is the number of unread rows in `notifications` table.

```
 read | unread |          output should be           
------|--------|-------------------------------------
 3    | 8      | 11 rows                             
 12   | 5      | 15 rows (5 unread, 10 read)         
 20   | 30     | 32 rows (30 unread, 2 read)         
 10   | 0      | 10 rows (0 unread, 10 read)         
 10   | 1      | 11 rows (1 unread, 10 read)         
 10   | 6      | 15 rows (6 unread, 9 read)          
 100  | 3      | 15 rows (3 unread, 12 read)         
 3    | 100    | 102 rows (100 unread, 2 read)
```

---

Here is my current query, it doesn't support second condition.

```
SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
) UNION 
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id 
 ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
 LIMIT 15
)
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc;
```

Comment: Just select all unseen and(union with) 15 seen. After that truncate (client-side) to 15 if there less than 15 unseen.

Comment: Your second subquery missed `seen is not null` condition

Comment: @vp_arth Your idea is containing some helpful points. thank you.

Comment: @vp_arth Why you don't write an answer? I'll accept it as accepted one. Noted that I'm using PHP as my server side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution. To add second condition *(selecting two read rows if there is more than 15 unread rows)*, I have to use one more `UNION`. Something like this:

```
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
)UNION
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp
 FROM notification n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 2
)UNION 
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id 
 ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
 LIMIT 15
)
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc;
```

The first subquery gets all unseen rows. The second gets two seen rows. The third gets fifteen rows. The `UNION` removes duplicates, but no other limit is applied.

Comment: and now I know difference between `union` and `union all` :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = 123 AND seen IS NULL

UNION

(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
FROM ( 
 SELECT id, event, seen, n.id_user, time_stamp, un.CNT
    FROM notifications n
    JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, id_user
        FROM notifications
        WHERE id_user = 123 and seen is NULL
        group by id_user
        ) un
    ON n.id_user = un.id_user
    WHERE CNT > 15
) t1
WHERE t1.SEEN is not NULL
LIMIT 2)

UNION

SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
FROM ( 
 SELECT id, event, seen, n.id_user, time_stamp, un.CNT
    FROM notifications n
    JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, id_user
        FROM notifications
        WHERE id_user = 123 and seen is NULL
        group by id_user
        ) un
    ON n.id_user = un.id_user
    WHERE CNT < 15
) t1
WHERE t1.SEEN is not NULL
```

Comment: Oh .. that's a pretty complex query. I don't know it works or not, but I prefer don't use it. I feel there is a more simple approach. Thank you anyway and +1 for your try.

Answer (score 1):

Just select all unseen and(union with) 15 seen.

```
SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 15)
```

So, you now have all unread and up to 15 read notifications.

After that you are able to truncate (client-side) to 15 if there less than 15 unseen.

Best place for do it, I think, is fetch loop.
Just count seen/unseen and break the loop at point you reach enough rows.

Some pseudocode php:

```
$read = $unread = 0;

while($row = $db->fetch()) {
  if ($row['seen']) $read++;
  if (!$row['seen']) $unread++;
  // ...
  if ($weHaveEnoughRows) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this one,

table T returns read notifications with row number order by time_stamp desc.

You then select from T where row <= GREATEST(15-Count() of unread,2).

and then union all with unread

```
SELECT id,event,seen,time_stamp 
FROM 
  (SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp,@row:=@row+1 as row 
   FROM notifications n,(SELECT @row := 0)r
   WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY time_stamp desc
   )T
WHERE T.row <= GREATEST(15-
                   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notifications n
                    WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL),2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = :id
 AND seen is NULL
)
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc,time_stamp desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
SET @`id_user` := 123;

SELECT `id`, `event`, `seen`, `time_stamp`
FROM (SELECT `id`, `event`, `seen`, `time_stamp`, @`unread` := @`unread` + 1
      FROM `notifications`, (SELECT @`unread` := 0) `unr`
      WHERE `id_user` = @`id_user` AND `seen` IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `id`, `event`, `seen`, `time_stamp`, @`read` := @`read` + 1
      FROM `notifications`, (SELECT @`read` := 0) `r`
      WHERE `id_user` = @`id_user` AND `seen` IS NOT NULL
            AND (
                 @`read` < (15 - @`unread`) OR
                 ((15 - @`unread`) < 0 AND @`read` < 2)
            )
) `source`;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fd704/2)

Comment: However in your fiddle, there is 18 unread rows (`seen = null`) and the output is 18 rows `:-)` ..! expected result is 20 rows.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right .. two of those 18 unread rows are belong to another user.

Comment: Your query just has a small problem .. it doesn't has any ordering .. I want this order: `ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc`, May you please add it to your query?

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps simplify the query and use some post-processing logic in the application to handle the edge case around having 14 or 15 rows that are unread.  Just select up to 17 rows instead of 15 and, as you loop through the result set in your client application, simply don't bother retrieving rows 16 and 17 unless rows 14 and or 15 are unread.

That query could be as simple as:

```
SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
FROM notifications n
WHERE id_user = :id
ORDER BY seen DESC, time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 17
```

Comment: Thank for your effort but I believe you didn't understand my point. `LIMIT 17` limits the output to 17 rows in max. What happens if there is 20 unread rows? As I said, I always want to select **all** unread rows.